# Jquery Accordion Expand and collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

In my Wordpress Learning Management System site which is using the WPLMS theme found Themeforest, I have an accordion course sidebar with multiple sections or modules and each section has multiple units or lessons inside it.

I have managed to make the first section expand as default and make the other section collapsed.See the screenshot here:

[image]

However, once I finish the lessons on Section 1 and move onto Section 2, the Section 1 tab does not collapse and expand Section 2.

I have used the css and jquery code given from this forum link here:

http://vibethemes.com/forums/forum/wordpress-html-css/wordpress-themes/wplms/tips-tricks-docs/9028-tip-how-to-make-the-course-curriculum-accordion-style

to get the above accordion functionality to work so far and I am hoping if you can guide me to get this accordion functionality working.

Comment: It would help if you showed code examples of what you have tried

Comment: I have used the exact same code as given in this forum link: http://vibethemes.com/forums/forum/wordpress-html-css/wordpress-themes/wplms/tips-tricks-docs/9028-tip-how-to-make-the-course-curriculum-accordion-style

Comment: @ArthurKorchagin, if you're going to go through questions editing to embed the screenshots, I'd recommend also looking closer to see if there are other obvious improvements that should be made. What you're doing isn't unhelpful, but in the review queue, I've gone in and done additional easy, obvious cleanup on almost every suggested edit of yours that I've reviewed.